# Recursive Iteration over nested list without Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, slice, matrix-multiplication

I would like to iterate over a nested list. I only found a solution with Numpy (-> in the else case), but I was wondering if this is possible without Numpy.

```
import numpy as np

def matrix_mulitplication(A, B):
    n = A.shape[0]

    if n == 1:
        return A * B
    else:
        i = int(n / 2)

        C = np.zeros((n, n), dtype=np.int)

        C[:i, :i] = matrix_mulitplication(A[:i, :i], B[:i, :i]) + matrix_mulitplication(A[:i, i:], B[i:, :i])

        C[:i, i:] = matrix_mulitplication(A[:i, :i], B[:i, i:]) + matrix_mulitplication(A[:i, i:], B[i:, i:])

        C[i:, :i] = matrix_mulitplication(A[i:, :i], B[:i, :i]) + matrix_mulitplication(A[i:, i:], B[i:, :i])

        C[i:, i:] = matrix_mulitplication(A[i:, :i], B[:i, i:]) + matrix_mulitplication(A[i:, i:], B[i:, i:])

        return C

x = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
y = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

print(matrix_mulitplication(x, y))
```

Output:

```
[[ 7 10]
 [15 22]]
```

My Idea for the first slicing case:

```
c_one = [C[i][0:int(len(C) / 2)] for i in range(0,int(len(C) / 2))]
```

Comment: Just 2 levels of nesting?

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko Exactly

Comment: `itertools.chain(*nested_list)`?

Comment: @NickA updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to replicate your nxn block subdivision.  I used a `blk` helper function to replicate the 2d array slicing:

```
import numpy as np

def matrix_mulitplication(A, B):
    def blk(x,i1,i2):
        return [row[i2] for row in x[i1]]

    n = len(A) # A.shape[0]

    if n == 1:
        #print(A)
        return A[0][0] * B[0][0]
    else:
        i = int(n / 2)
        i1, i2 = slice(None,i), slice(i,None)
        #C = np.zeros((n, n), dtype=np.int)
        C1 = matrix_mulitplication(blk(A, i1, i1), blk(B,i1,i1)) +\
             matrix_mulitplication(blk(A, i1, i2), blk(B,i2,i1))

        C2 = matrix_mulitplication(blk(A, i1, i1), blk(B,i1,i2)) +\
             matrix_mulitplication(blk(A, i1, i2), blk(B,i2,i2))

        C3 = matrix_mulitplication(blk(A, i2, i1), blk(B,i1,i1)) +\
             matrix_mulitplication(blk(A, i2, i2), blk(B,i2,i1))

        C4 = matrix_mulitplication(blk(A, i2, i1), blk(B,i1,i2)) +\
             matrix_mulitplication(blk(A, i2, i2), blk(B,i2,i2))
        C = [[C1,C2],[C3,C4]]
        return C

x = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
y = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)

z = matrix_mulitplication([[1]],[[2]])
print(z)
z = matrix_mulitplication(x.tolist(), x.tolist())
print(z)
print(x@x)
z = matrix_mulitplication(y.tolist(), y.tolist())
print(z)
print(y@y)
```

This works for one level of recursion, but not two:

```
1253:~/mypy$ python3 stack50552791.py 
2
[[7, 10], [15, 22]]
[[ 7 10]
 [15 22]]
[[[[4, 5], [20, 29], [52, 57], [132, 145]], [[6, 7], [38, 47], [62, 67], [158, 171]]], [[[36, 53], [52, 77], [212, 233], [292, 321]], [[70, 87], [102, 127], [254, 275], [350, 379]]]]
[[ 56  62  68  74]
 [152 174 196 218]
 [248 286 324 362]
 [344 398 452 506]]
```

The problem with the 2nd level is that `matrix_mulitplication` returns a nested list, and list `+` is defined as concatenate, not element addition.  So I'll have to define another helper function (or 2) to address that properly.

### a bit better

```
def matrix_mulitplication(A, B):
    def blk(x,i1,i2):
        return [row[i2] for row in x[i1]]
    def add(x,y):
        if isinstance(x, list):
            return [add(i,j) for i,j in zip(x,y)]
        else:
            return x+y
    n = len(A) # A.shape[0]

    if n == 1:
        return A[0][0] * B[0][0]
    else:
        i = int(n / 2)
        i1, i2 = slice(None,i), slice(i,None)
        #C = np.zeros((n, n), dtype=np.int)
        C1 = add(matrix_mulitplication(blk(A, i1, i1), blk(B,i1,i1)) ,\
             matrix_mulitplication(blk(A, i1, i2), blk(B,i2,i1)))

        C2 = add(matrix_mulitplication(blk(A, i1, i1), blk(B,i1,i2)) ,\
             matrix_mulitplication(blk(A, i1, i2), blk(B,i2,i2)))

        C3 = add(matrix_mulitplication(blk(A, i2, i1), blk(B,i1,i1)) ,\
             matrix_mulitplication(blk(A, i2, i2), blk(B,i2,i1)))

        C4 = add(matrix_mulitplication(blk(A, i2, i1), blk(B,i1,i2)) ,\
             matrix_mulitplication(blk(A, i2, i2), blk(B,i2,i2)))
        C = [[C1,C2],[C3,C4]]
        return C
```

and for the 4x4 case

```
[[[[56, 62], [152, 174]], [[68, 74], [196, 218]]], [[[248, 286], [344, 398]], [[324, 362], [452, 506]]]]
[[ 56  62  68  74]
 [152 174 196 218]
 [248 286 324 362]
 [344 398 452 506]]
```

The numbers are all there, but in a 4-depth nested list.

So not only is breaking up the nested list into a 2d blocks more awkward than with arrays, reassembling them is also awkward.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm

Without reading the Strassen algorithm in detail, it is evident that any claims about its efficiency, assume that `A_ij` indexing (for single elements or blocks) is efficient, both when fetching values and setting (`C_ij`).  With lists, `A[i]` or `A[i:j]` is fairly efficient, but the `[row[i2] for row in x[i1]` is not.

Assembling blocks with `[[a,b],[c,d]]` is ok, but anything comparable to `[[C_11,C_12],[C_21,C_22]]` where `C` elements are blocks as opposed to scalars, is complicated.

It seems that the Strassen goal is to reduce the required number of multiplications.  That assumes that (scalar) multiplications are the most expensive part of matrix multiplication. With a Python lists that clearly isn't the case.  Accessing elements is more expensive.

### a numpy cheat

I could rework the `z` from the 4x4 case with

```
arr = np.array(z)
arr = arr.transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(4,4)
```

This is so much easier in `numpy`.

Answer (score 1):

In `numpy` you are just doing the 2d matrix multiplication, which can be expressed in several ways, such as `np.dot`, `np.einsum` or the (newish) `@` operator

```
In [1]: x = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
In [2]: x@x
Out[2]: 
array([[ 7, 10],
       [15, 22]])
```

To do the same with lists, let's approach the task in steps

In algebra I learned to run one finger across the rows, and the other down the columns.  So lets do the with a list comprehension:

```
In [6]: x1 = x.tolist()
In [7]: x2 = x.tolist()
In [8]: [[(row1,col2) for col2 in zip(*x2)] for row1 in x1]
Out[8]: [[([1, 2], (1, 3)), ([1, 2], (2, 4))], [([3, 4], (1, 3)), ([3, 4], (2, 4))]]
```

The pairing of rows and columns looks right.  `zip(*xl)` is an idiom for 'transposing' a list (equivalent to `x.T` in numpy)

Now define a helper function that does 1d multiplication:

```
In [9]: def mult(row,col):
   ...:     return [i*j for i,j in zip(row,col)]
   ...: 
   ...: 
In [10]: [[mult(row1,col2) for col2 in zip(*x2)] for row1 in x1]
Out[10]: [[[1, 6], [2, 8]], [[3, 12], [6, 16]]]
```

Now add the summation.  I could go back an modify the `mult`, but doing it in the outer comprehension is just as easy.

```
In [12]: [[sum(mult(row1,col2)) for col2 in zip(*x2)] for row1 in x1]
Out[12]: [[7, 10], [15, 22]]
```

Or combining all the list comprehensions, to make one unreadable line:

```
In [14]: [[sum(i*j for i,j in zip(row1,col2)) for col2 in zip(*x2)] for row1 in x1]
Out[14]: [[7, 10], [15, 22]]
```

---

For this 2x2 example my results are the same yours, but you are taking a different approach, splitting the original arrays into blocks.  May work ok with `numpy` arrays which slice nicely.  But I'm not sure it helps with lists.  We'd have to play around with other examples.

Mine works with a 3x3 array

```
In [29]: y = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
In [30]: [[sum(mult(row1,col2)) for col2 in zip(*y.tolist())] for row1 in y.toli
    ...: st()]
Out[30]: [[15, 18, 21], [42, 54, 66], [69, 90, 111]]
In [31]: y@y
Out[31]: 
array([[ 15,  18,  21],
       [ 42,  54,  66],
       [ 69,  90, 111]])
```

Your's fails with a shape broadcasting error on a 3x3, but works the same on a 4x4.

```
In [32]: y = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
In [33]: y@y
Out[33]: 
array([[ 56,  62,  68,  74],
       [152, 174, 196, 218],
       [248, 286, 324, 362],
       [344, 398, 452, 506]])
In [34]: [[sum(mult(row1,col2)) for col2 in zip(*y.tolist())] for row1 in y.toli
    ...: st()]
Out[34]: 
[[56, 62, 68, 74],
 [152, 174, 196, 218],
 [248, 286, 324, 362],
 [344, 398, 452, 506]]
In [35]: matrix_mulitplication(y,y)
Out[35]: 
array([[ 56,  62,  68,  74],
       [152, 174, 196, 218],
       [248, 286, 324, 362],
       [344, 398, 452, 506]])
```

So your recursion is to break a 4x4 into 2x2 blocks and then down to 1x1.  Mine breaks the 2d arrays into 1d sums-of-products.

Comment: First, thank you for the long explanation. I know that there are simpler approaches of matrix multiplication, but my approach was to use the divide and conquer paradigm (the pre-step of the Strassen algorithm). My question was less about different approaches but more about slicing operators for nested lists that are possible without numpy.

Comment: Slicing nxn blocks of a nested list is possible but messy.  You'll be making new lists, no any kind of view.  `[row[:i] for row in alist[:i]]`.